# svn cleanup and lockup throw the error "operation not supported"

Tags: svn

I am not sure why my svn is behaving so weird.

This is how I have my setup.

There is a svn repository on a machine called shivani_machine
and there are two accounts on this machine, shivani and papu

Shivani is a user that checksout of this repository on shivani_machine itself
and papu on another computer shivani_laptop

I added a bunch of files from shivani_laptop using username papu
I then attempted to update it from shivani_machine from username shivani

```
shivani@shivani_machine:/research$ svn update
svn: Can't open file '.svn/lock' operation not supported
shivani@shivani_machine:/research$ svn update
svn: Can't open file '.svn/lock' operation not supported
```

I even tried svn status and it does show that there is a lock in one of directories in research/mycode... 
but when I do a "ls" on that folder, I do not see a .svn/lock file in that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a `ls -a` to see directories starting with a `.` (dot).

Try running `svn cleanup` on your working directory before proceeding.

Comment: @Shivani Rao Go to `.svn` and delete the lock file. Like I said, `ls -a` is required to see `.svn`

Comment: I am unable to find the lock file... ls -a in any .svn directory does not show any lock file.. so its really confusing